# python text to second y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make my first plots in python using matplotlib, but i would like the text in the plot to be "outside" the plot i.e. next to the line instead of above it or under it.

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(mean, diff, color='k')

plt.axhline(md,           color='black', linestyle='-', lw=3)
plt.axhline(md + 1.96*sd, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(md - 1.96*sd, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(0, color='black', linestyle='--')

plt.ylim(-max(diff)*2, max(diff)*2)
plt.xlabel('Mean')
plt.ylabel('Difference')
plt.title('Bland altman plot for ' + variable)

txt1=('+1.96 SD')
txt2=('-1.96 SD')
txt3 =('Mean')

x = max(mean)
plt.text(x, md+1.96*sd, txt1, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom', fontweight='bold')
plt.text(x, md-1.96*sd, txt2, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top', fontweight='bold')
plt.text(x, 0.1, txt3)
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a label to y-axis to show the value of y for a horizontal line in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877747/add-a-label-to-y-axis-to-show-the-value-of-y-for-a-horizontal-line-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display y axis value horizontal line drawn In bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560801/display-y-axis-value-horizontal-line-drawn-in-bar-chart)

Comment: I would consider this to be a duplicate of either of the above questions (possibly others as well). However since you said that you're making your "first plots", it may be that transformations are not easy enough to understand and I therefore provided you with a simpler solution down below.

Answer (score 0):

The main ingredient you still need to position the labels at the edge of the axes, is the coordinate of the edge of the axes. You can get those via `plt.gca().get_xlim()`. The upper limit can then be used as `x` position of the text label.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.normal(size=(12))
Y = np.random.normal(size=(12))

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='k')

plt.axhline(Y.mean(),           color='black', linestyle='-', lw=3)
plt.axhline(Y.mean() + 1.96*Y.std(), color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(Y.mean() - 1.96*Y.std(), color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(0, color='black', linestyle='--')

txt1=(' +1.96 SD')
txt2=(' -1.96 SD')
txt3 =(' Mean')

x0,x1 = plt.gca().get_xlim()
plt.text(x1, Y.mean() + 1.96*Y.std(), txt1, ha='left', va='center', fontweight='bold')
plt.text(x1, Y.mean() - 1.96*Y.std(), txt2, ha='left', va='center', fontweight='bold')
plt.text(x1, 0, txt3, ha='left', va='center',)

# make more space on right side to host the labels
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this is the very basic (but also quite understandable) version.

If you're comfortable with transformations, you can use the technique in this question:

[Add a label to y-axis to show the value of y for a horizontal line in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877747/add-a-label-to-y-axis-to-show-the-value-of-y-for-a-horizontal-line-in-matplotlib)

Comment: If the x-axis is a date then what should be replaced  with x1 in ````plt.text(x1, Y.mean() + 1.96*Y.std(), txt1, ha='left', va='center', fontweight='bold')````